# Problem with symmetry in sculpting mode

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, origin, multiresolution, boolean-modifier

After I used the boolean modifier, and the multiresolution and the remesh to soften the object, I went back to the sculpting mode and my symmetry was a little bit off.
I already tried with the ctrl+a and apply to all transformations (and rotation too), the origin point is in the center and the 3D cursor too. I even tried with importing and exporting it but for some reason the file doesn't appear. What should I do?

Comment: Hello, it should work, maybe your object is asymmetrical? Symmetrize it in Edit mode: Select all then Mesh > Symmetrize?

Comment: @moonboots Hello! I did that, but my object is only symmetrical on its sides, not in the top, and it symmetrized the whole object, causing the top to lose its shape. But if I only select the part I want to symmetrize, will that work?

Comment: If your object is not symmetrical, it may be the reason why when you sculpt it you won't have the same thing on the other side? You can symmetrize a part only but it may not be easy to rework afterwards

Comment: @moonboots Yes, is only symmetrical on the sides, but still, the symmetry is not working, and the part I want to be symmetrical is only the sides. I'll try to symmetrize it. They're just a few details actually, I don't need to work it too much.

Comment: Maybe share your file?